# Launcher for python application on windows

Tags: python, windows, launcher

Currently I'm using a `batch` file like the following one  for starting a `python` application on windows.

```
@echo off
pushd ..
call .venv\Scripts\activate.bat
set PYTHONPATH=%cd%
python -tt src/myapp.py
```

This activates the `virtualenv` and then launches the application. This is not very elegant since it opens a `CMD`-window and I can't do an application icon.

What's a better way to do this to make it more like a single application?

Comment: Code it directly in Python? Using subprocess.call and such?

Comment: you could at least avoid the `CMD` window by using `pythonw` rather than `python` in the last line

Comment: @codedstructure This does not influence the behavior since the command prompt is there because of the batch-file.

Comment: @Nil Does this also work for virtualenv?

Comment: It works for everything you can do on the command line if you use the shell=True parameter. Or still work for a lot of things without.

Comment: You don't need to activate virtualenv; instead of plain `python` use path to the Python binary inside virtualenv's folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you are satisfied with a really simple solution, try something like this:

Create a file "start_my_app.vbs" (it is Visual Basic Script) with the following code:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "pythonw.exe my_app.py"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Just update the code above for whatever you need to run (virtualenv etc.) before your python file. However, you cannot change the icon of vbs file. But when you create a shortcut to this vbs file, then you can change the icon of the shortcut very easily (right click - Properties - Change icon...).